# detect size of the object without image resizing

Tags: python, image, opencv, scale

*Main idea:*

I have different images of the same size: 2048x2176. There's the same object at all these images that I try to detect using 'findContours' method. And I know that the amount of pixels for this object is between 'lower and upper bound' [depending on the image]. Lower bound is equal 270 and upper bound is equal 720.

I also have images of size 1024x1088. I've found that the lower and upper bounds for this size are equal 135 and 360 respectively.

*Problem:*

How does this scaling work? At the moment I use only 2 image sizes but I would like to be able to use images of different sizes and scale everything automatically in the future.

*Example:*

[image: Image of size 1024x1088]

[image: Image of size 2048x2176]

I'd love to know what is the range in pixels for the contour of the circle at the 2nd image, knowing the range of pixels at the 1st image (lower and upper bound[mentioned higher]) [without resizing the images] [I need some formula to make it work for images of different sizes].

*Some code to make it more clear:*

```
constImageSize = 4456448  #image of size 2048x2176
lowBorder = 270  
highBorder = 720  

if (imageSize == constImageSize):
    lowBorder *= 1
    highBorder *= 1
else:
    lowBorder /= 2
    highBorder /= 2
```

*Note:*

1. I can't do resizing of the image.
2. I also have other parameters that depend on this scaling (e.g.
   distance between 2 different objects at the same image).

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please post example images? If you are trying to recognize whether the shape of an object in both images is the same, then you could try using cv2.matchShapes(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317

Comment: I've tried to explain the problem higher (make the edit). I've added some example images (in reality i have other images [i can't share them] but these examples should make the issue clearer). @fmw42

Comment: They scale by the ratio of the areas of the input images. `small feature area = large feature area * (small image area / large image area)`

Comment: 1) What do you mean under large feature area (e.g. 'lower bound' [it's just a number of pixels] ? 2) if yes, then e.g. 'large image area' is 2048x2176 = 4456448 ; 'small image area' is 1026x1088 = 1114112; 3) Then: 'small feature area' = 270 (lower bound) * (1114112/4456448) = 67,5 ~= 67. 4) But i know that 'low bound' for the second image is about 135. So, what am I doing wrong? Under 'lower and upper bound' i mean mix and max number of pixels for the object [circle in my example]. @fmw42

Comment: I meant that you know the area (pixel count) of each objects in the large image (large feature area). From that and the areas of the two images (total pixels), you can compute the area (pixel count) of the objects in the small image (small feature area). You do the math for each object separately using the equation above that I provided)

Comment: `small area lower bound = 270 * (1024*1088) / (2048*2176)`